Bootstrap 5 Modal not showing
I have included Bootstrap 5 as a Nuget package and trying to set up a modal on a page. Other aspects of Bootstrap 5 are working as intended.
  <div class="col-12">
  <button type="button" class="btn entry-button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#logInModal">Log In</button>
  <div class="modal" id="logInModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          It works
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          It works
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn entry-button">Create Account</button>
</div>

I am doing this in an Angular project with an ASP.NET back end.
Edit: The button appears fine in the window and I can click it, and there's no errors occurring in the console.
I haven't played around with the 'index.html' file. This is it:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ActreelClient</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>

All the other bootstrap features work fine.

Any more information you can share would be appreciated. Is the button showing? Are there any JS errors that get thrown when you click the button?

Can you share the JS/CSS file for Bootstrap that you imported in the index.html?

Bootstrap modal requires popper.js as a dependency as well as Bootstraps own JS package, have you installed and referenced these correctly? I generally use ng-bootstrap which provides a convenient Angular wrapper for Bootstrap, and has an extremely straightforward installation using a single command (schematic) ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap which handles all of the configuration for you.

how are you using it, in a component, template..? data-bs attributes might not work with dynamically added content, so you'll most likely need to initiate modal with JS in angular

I simply went to the angular.json file and added a reference to the bootstrap.js file in the scripts section.
"scripts": [
  "scripts/bootstrap.js"
]


install bootstrap and @types/boostrap
npm i bootstrap
npm i @types/boostrap

Change your angular.json to include the bootstrap.css and the bootstrap.bundle.min.js
"scripts": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"],
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/global_styles.css"],

Just copy the example in bootstrap
NOTE: in this stackblitz I use the most popular bootstrap components if you want some inspiration.

This essentially sorted it but what I did was slightly different.
